# How to make @ turn math symbols bold

Tags: math-mode, catcodes, boldmath, mathcode

I would like to change the meaning of `@` in math mode to be such that it takes the object following it and makes it bold, e.g. `$@x$` should produce a bold math x, `$@\alpha$` should produce a bold alpha, and `$@{\hat x^2}$` should make everything inside the curlies bold.

The following code doesn't work; I'm out of my depth.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}


\begingroup
\lccode`\~=`@
\lowercase{\endgroup
\def~#1~{\boldsymbol{#1}}%
}%
\mathcode`@="8000



\begin{document}
$@x$   % I want this to produce a boldface math x
\end{document}
```

Comment: ``\def~#1{\bm{#1}}``

Comment: Add an answer and I'll $\checkmark$ it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you're defining is `$@x@`. If you just want `@`, it should be

```
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`@ \lowercase{\endgroup\def~#1}{\bm{#1}}
\mathcode`@="8000
```

Complete example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begingroup\lccode`\~=`@ \lowercase{\endgroup\def~#1}{\bm{#1}}
\mathcode`@="8000

\begin{document}

$x+@x$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Enter image description here...?

Comment: @daleif egreg is new here, he hasn't quite mastered the site format.